# Show servlet data in jsp

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet which is reading data from a database and populating a list. I want to display this list in a jsp file but I am not managing to display the rows. Could someone indicate what I am doing wrong please? These are the files:

ListCars.java (servlet)

```
package servlets;

[imports]

@WebServlet(name="ListCars", loadOnStartup = 1,urlPatterns={"/ListCars"})
public class ListCars extends HttpServlet {
@EJB
private CarsFacade carsFacade;


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getSession(true);
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    List dbData = carsFacade.findAll();

    request.setAttribute("data",dbData);

}


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    processRequest(request, response);

    String url = "/index.jsp";

    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

    // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
    String url = "/index.jsp";

    try {
        request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
    <title>Car Hire</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="widgetBar">
                <div class="headerWidget">
                   <a href="#">
                        Login
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="headerWidget"></div>
                <div class="headerWidget">

                    <a href="#">
                        Register
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>       
        </div>

        <div id="indexMidColumn">
            <div id="welcomeText">
                <p>Car Hire</p>
            </div>


                <table border="1" width="303">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="119"><b>ID</b></td>

                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items='${data}' var='CarsAv' varStatus="loop">
                        <tr><td>${CarsAv.Brand}</td></tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>

        </div>

    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ListCars</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.ListCars</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ListCars</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ListCars</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: The code looks fine. Probably you're not getting data from your database. Review the results from your `carsFacade.findAll()` method.

Comment: Which URL are you accessing in the browser? Does it end with `ListCars`?

Comment: When I add a method to read the database and print it from the servlet, the data is printed and the list is populated but when I try and pass the data to the jsp page it does not show anything.

Comment: @DavidLevesque The URL is http://localhost:8080/CarHireAssignment-war/ListCars and when I remove the /ListCars the index page is shown but the table is not populated with the data I want. If it makes any difference, I am using an Enterprise Application

Comment: Ok but with the `/ListCars` does it display the data?

Comment: Yes if I do a method which ierates through the list the fields required are displayed. Ex: Cars elem = (Cars) iterator.next();                out.println("<b>"+mycar.getId()+ "<b> />");